# How Can I show data on Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Hello all brother this is my controller

```
model.addAttribute("getDataHead",cartHeadStockinService.getDatahead());
System.out.println(model);
```

and after that I syso to review i get like this

```
 getDataHead=[Cart_HeadStockin [id=101, invoice=fsdfsdf, po=, remark=, supplyId=1, date=null]]
```

and I want to show this on my Thymeleaf

```
th:object="${getDataHead}" 

th:text="${invoice}"
```

Comment: As the error states `getDataHead` appears to be an array.  If you want to output an array, you have to index into it.  Or change it into a regular object.  Does this output? `<span th:text="${getDataHead[0].invoice}"></span>` -- and if so, what do you need to change in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Hello friend thats great you are able put the context variables in your Model

The way to print the text of your in your Thymeleaf is like this

```
<span th:text="${getDataHead.invoice}"></span>
```

Here is a reference [link](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html) to Thymeleaf documentation

Comment: EL1008E: Property or field 'invoice' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public or not valid?

Comment: I must be try to make like th:text="${getDataHead.invoice}" but is so error i don't know why but at my controller i can get data already but i can't show thymeleaf

Comment: can you provide the class of getDataHead ?